# "Жрать" о животных

Tags: лексика

Здравствуйте!

Скажите пожалуйста, является ли употребление глагола "жрать" по отношению к животным нейтральным и культурным в официальном русском языке ( к примеру в программе новостей или научных/газетных статьях, НЕ в художественной литературе). Меня интересует именно данная форма этого глагола, а не производные, такие как  например "пожирать" ( т.к. по-моему "саранча пожирает посевы" или " львы пожирают оленью тушу" допустимо и нейтрально). За приведение аргументов и ссылки на источники, была бы отдельно очень благодарна. С уважением, Александра

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5):

По отношению к животным слово жрать является разговорным. В учебниках, энциклопедиях, да в той же передаче "В мире животных" мы скорее услышим (прочитаем) едят, питаются, чем жрут.

Жрать. Несов. перех. разг.-сниж. 1. Есть, поедать. 2. перен. Сильно кусать (о насекомых).
Толковый словарь Ефремовой  Здесь, как видим, стилистическая помета дана перед толкованием, т.е. относится к слову в любом значении.